# Can I use なる with positive verbs?

Tags: grammar

So I find the pattern `Negative verb/ i-adjective + なる` very convenient, because, at least I think, it shows the change from a state into another.

For instance:

> それをもうしないと約束するなら、怒らなくなる。

For me it puts emphasis in the actual state of being angry and the change that might come to a different state. While just using `怒らない` would just mean that you won't be angry.

Now my question is, **can we do that with positive verbs? And if we can, is it common/natural to do so?**

I don't know exactly how that could be done, but my attempt would be something like this:

> それをすれば、怒るようになる。 - If you do that, I'll change from my "not angry" state, to an angry state.

or maybe:

> それをすれば、怒ってなってくる。

Thanks in advance! Also, besides grammar, if any of my assumptions are incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: Changed all instances of 起こる (to happen) to 怒る (to get angry), as that definition was indicated in your English translations.

Comment: @user27280 ohh, my bad, I haven't use that verb for a while so I forgot the kanji and conjugation. Sorry!

Comment: No problem:) It happens.

Comment: While おこるようになる itself is fine, you don't use it for your own action.

Comment: @user4092 I thought you'd be able to use in a way similar to 英語を話せるようになりたい

Comment: Maybe, I should have said "your own volitional action" or so. Being mad is up to you, is done at your responsibility and not matter of general tendency like climate.

Comment: @user4092 my main goal was using なる and I thought that ように was the grammatical tool I needed to use that. I don't know how ように invalidate my attempt, could you tell me? My goal is (if possible)using なる to emphasize the transition between one state to another. Eg: "hungry" and "not hungry", "angry" and not "angry" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand 怒るようになる or おこらなくなる. It doesn't mean state change from being not angry to being angry or vise versa, but to acquire furious tendency or so.

If you combine with an adjective, you can use 腹立たしい → 腹立たしくなる. However, it doesn't give the effect you wanted. It rather softens or blurs the boundary.

What you wanted will be （そう しないと約束したら）もう怒らない (recommended) / 怒るのをやめる and （そう したら）おこる.

Comment: "but to acquire furious tendency or so." means to become able to ...(something) ? So the behavior is different when it comes to adjectives? While it does not work for 怒る. 「そろそろ帰らないなら、眠くなる」 is a valid way to say "If I don't go home soon, I'll be(become) sleepy"? Or would 「そろそろ帰らないなら、眠い」 be the right choice, instead?

Comment: The behavior is same as that of adjectives. 怒るよう or 怒らない are a state of possibility. そろそろ帰らないと眠くなる is correct. (そろそろ帰らないなら would mean "if you are not supposed to go home soon")

Answer (score 0):

While I did find a couple examples that appear to follow the same construction that you are asking about (て＋なる）, but they are very few and only coincidentally linked. The alternatives which already exist and are in common use (which have been mentioned by yourself) would be the best forms to use.

As verbs such as 怒る and 喜ぶ already have the meaning of ‘to enter a state of ____’ implicit, it would seem redundant to place なる directly next to them.

For this reason, the alternatives: 「怒るようになる」 &　「怒ってくる」 would be best:

> 怒るようになる /  怒るようになってくる -  ‘Enter a state of getting angry (become angry).’.

.

> それをすれば、怒ってなってくる。

While I do not find the above difficult to understand or implement, I think that most native speakers would avoid using such a form, as it just doesn’t sound as natural or grammatical.

Maybe someone will be able to provide a better, more grammatical explanation than mine.

Comment: I’m not stuck with your answer, I’m thankful for it! I will study all the points you presented! And if another answer comes, it will be good to have a second opinion on the matter. Thanks :)

Comment: 上のほうのリンクの「お腹が空いてなる」は、２つとも「お腹が空いて、（「グゥ～」って音が）[鳴]{な}る」って意味です。で、「走ってなる」のほうは、上から、「 **走って、なる**べく～」と、「 **走って** （疲労骨折に） **なる** 」と、「 **走ってなる**なる。~~お疲れなるなる。」（←「なるちゃん」っていう人が言ってる言葉遊びみたいなもの）って意味で使われてます

Comment: ムリヤリ文例探しをして失敗してしまいました。最初、「なる」と「音」がもしかしたらつながっているかも知れないことに悩んだけど．．．入れるのをやめた方がよかった。回答のその分を消しますね。「走ってなる」もいう人がいても僅かな数なのでそれもなくします。フィードバックありがとうございました。

Comment: Is the change halfway through from 怒る to 送る intentional? Also, is the やる usage attached to verbs actually synonymous with する？My impression is that say for 怒るー＞怒ってやる it would be #17ｲ here: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/223431/meaning/m0u/, but we may need a native speaker to really answer this one.
Edit: nvm @Schokolade is on it.

Comment: @mindful The change midway through was meant as an example to emphasize that although something might seem like a logical expression from a grammar standpoint, if it is not used by the majority of a population it should probably not be used.  また文法マスターにやられた！

Comment: `「送ってやる」 but hardly ever 「送ってする」... even though やる and する share the same meaning` -- This is because... やる has another meaning, "to give", and can be a subsidiary verb (補助動詞) following て-form (「送ってやる」≂「送ってあげる」). する doesn't work like that.　And..  なる can't be a subsidiary verb following te-form (except in forms 「～てならない (can't help ~ing)」and「～てなるか・～てなるものか (will never~)」).　Edit: ごめん、コメント書き直して再投稿したから順番おかしくなった

Comment: @Schokolade & Mindful  Thanks for the comments. I have removed a lot of the irrelevant/misleading/incorrect text. It's not about the downvotes, I just don't want to leave any information that, after reading, could cause someone to get confused.

Comment: 怒ってなってくる doesn't make sense at all.